# Laravel value of variable will not hold

Tags: php, laravel, debugging, laravel-9

I never saw this before. Hopefully I can explain it to you that you'll understand it.

My code:

```
$google2fa = app(Google2FA::class);

$secret = $google2fa->generateSecretKey();
$user = $this->verifyToken('authentication', $request->mail, $secret);
$g2faUrl = $google2fa->getQRCodeUrl(
    'name',
    $request->mail,
    $user['google_authentication']
);

$writer = new Writer(
    new ImageRenderer(
        new RendererStyle(400),
        new ImagickImageBackEnd()
    )
);

$qrcode_image = base64_encode($writer->writeString($g2faUrl));
return view('auth.register.admin.index', ['qrcode' => '', 'secret' => $user['google_authentication']]);
```

Above you see the array variable: `$user['google_authentication']` on the first part I create a secret token, then I save the secret in the verify method `verifyToken()`.
When I publish this secret on the view, it shows me a different secret then that i saved. But the weird part is, when I place a `var_dump()` in the code, then the secret in the view is the same as I saved.

The verify method just do a simple post api request to my middleware where I save the secret under the user, nothing special.

**What is wrong in here?**

- The view doesn't load twice, I already checked Laravel debug bar
- And why does it hold the value of the variable (`$user['google_authentication']`) when I use var_dump() in the code.

Comment: still no answer

Comment: still no answer